# Error while compiling in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, syntax-error, undefined-symbol

When trying to compile my file AverageRainfall.java, I keep getting an error for my variables that two symbols do not exist. I have included the affected code, which includes the two defined variables and the System.out.print command that is receiving the error.

```
System.out.println("Enter the rainfall, in inches, for each month. ");          
for(int y = 1; y <= years; y++)

  for(int m = 1; m <= NUM_MONTHS; m++);     

System.out.print("Year" + y + "month" + m + ": ");        
monthRain = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

What am I doing wrong that I consistently get this error for both `'y'` and `'m'`:

```
AverageRainfall.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
```

After adding the changes suggested by first commenter, I no longer receive the 'cannot find symbol' error, but now I am told that 'y' and 'm' may not have initialized, and it is giving me an error for the while loop directly following it. Affected code:

```
    {
   System.out.println("Enter the rainfall, in inches, for each month. ");
      for(int y = 1; y <= years; y++){
         for(int m = 1; m <= NUM_MONTHS; m++){

          System.out.print("Year" + y + "month" + m + ": ");
          monthRain = keyboard.nextDouble(); 
         }
      }
         while (monthRain < 0)
      {
         System.out.print("Invalid. Enter 0 or greater: ");
         monthRain = keyboard.nextDouble();
      }
}
```

AverageRainfall.java:32: error: variable monthRain might not have been initialized

Comment: which line is line 26?

Comment: Get rid of the semicolon at the end of the second for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your m is wrongly initialized

```
int m = m;
```

This should fail as m does not have a value assigned yet.
Did you mean `int m = y;` ?

Comment: I changed it to m = 1 because the for loop goes from 1 to 12

Answer (score 0):

try to add brackets. also delete that semicolon after the inner loop

or

if you are using that two variables outside the loop then you must initialize that variable outside the loop.

```
System.out.println("Enter the rainfall, in inches, for each month. ");          
for(int y = 1; y <= years; y++){

  for(int m = m; m <= NUM_MONTHS; m++){     
     System.out.print("Year" + y + "month" + m + ": ");    
  }    
  monthRain = keyboard.nextDouble();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed that, but now I'm getting a new error related to my 'while' loop, and it's telling me my variables might not have been initialized.

Comment: what is the data type of the variable, how did you initialize it, if its an integer, you must assign a default value like 0

Comment: Try to print the variable `monthRain` before caling the while loop to see what's the current value or maybe it doesn't have.

Comment: That actually worked, now I have to go through and get all of my logical errors. Thank you so much!